# Is it likely possible that creation of our world needs a lot of steps called 'evolution'?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

Is it possible that creation of our world needs a lot of steps called 'evolution'? If it is like so would have been possible different scenarios for whatever we call a 'present' or 'living' on this world?

Comment: Are you asking if different courses of evolution could have led to the same present we observe?

Comment: Do you mean, 'Has anyone really been far even as decided to use even go want to do look more like' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the length of the time-scale.

When you try to asses the changes with a long time-scale, you will feel each change as steps. That is, in that sense, creation of our world needs a lot of steps called 'evolution'. But if the time-scale is so small, you won't feel so.

Answer (score 0):

"Evolution" is an exhaustively documented observation and record of the passage of geologic time. There is no 'creation', there is only now, and our gravest responsibility is to keenly, objectively, and scientifically observe what we can of the past, revealed by the evidence of our senses. And by 'senses', I mean the sum total of the magnificent tools at our disposal, from electron microscopes to space telescopes and everything in between.